# ASP.NET Core web service attempting to connect to SQL Server using local machine account when SQL account is set

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Our ASP.NET Web Service has the following SQL connection string in its `Startup` class:

`"Data Source=SQLServerInstance; Initial Catalog=Db; User Id=SQLAccountUsername; Password=password; Trusted_Connection=True"`

And yet we get failed login exceptions because it's attempting to login as the local machine account, `DOMAIN\Server$`

How is this even possible?

Comment: With `Trusted_Connection=True` you are trying to connect using Windows authentication. Use `Trusted_Connection=False` in your connection string to connect using SQL authentication with defined `user` and `password`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that also implied windows auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using windows authentication by setting TrustedConnection=true. Set it to false if you want to connect through user credentials.

Comment: Ah I knew it'd be something daft like this. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Please Mark this as an answer, so that other could get benefit from it.